# What does this context mean: (Monad m, (~) * a ())?

Tags: haskell

I've found the following class instance : `(Monad m, (~) * a ()) => LaTeXC (LaTeXT m a)`, but can't quite understand its context.

What does `(~) * a ()` mean? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(~)` is type-level equality (you could write it as some variant of `=` or `==`, but the opinion was that this notation already had enough different meanings that introducing another would be confusing). `*` is the kind of types. So `(~) *` is the assertion that two (inhabitable) types are equal. In other words, the instance could also be written like this:

```
instance Monad m => LaTeXC (LaTeXT m ())
```

Why wasn't it? Well, it's a question of inference. The way it was written makes the compiler choose this instance even if it doesn't (yet) know that the final argument to `LaTeXT` is `()`, then forces that, whereas the proposed alternative instance would simply complain.

Comment: I've only ever seen this written infix as `a ~ ()` and imagine the prefix version would be `(~) a ()`. How does the kind `*` come into it? It isn't mentioned in the documentation for [equality constraints](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html).

Comment: @Cirdec Yes, it is unfortunate, but GHC does not expose user-level syntax for kind-specific `~`. However, in its internal language, `~` takes a kind argument (and therefore when used needs to be applied to a kind). These kinds are inserted by kind inference, similarly to how Haskell's implicit `forall`s are converted into type-polymorphism and type application implicitly by type inference. GHC knows enough about this to strip the implicit kinds during printing, but haddock doesn't do the stripping.

Comment: This fully answers my question, thanks! I've also seen it only as `a ~ ()` and couldn't even imagine that `~` takes a kind argument.

Comment: Interesting. I was mentally parsing it as `Monad m, f (~) (a ())` except that `f` was named `*` and used infix, and was wondering what on earth would require such a context... :-)